# How to create full copy of a script using native JS?

Tags: javascript

There is the following task - I need to create a copy of script object (with all attributes except src), i.e if there is something like this:

```
<script src="1" async data-x="bb">
```

I need to create some script tag and insert it with the same attributes, i.e.

```
<script src="new_src" async data-x="bb">
```

I've tried to do the following one:

```
var script = document.currentScript;

insert('new_src', script.attributes);

function insert(src, attributes) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.attributes = attributes;
  script.src = src;

  oldScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, oldScript.nextSibling);
}
```

New script is inserted, but with empty attributes except src. How can I do it right? Thanks in advance! Only using native JS

Comment: `script.attributes = attributes;`? what is that?

Comment: `script.outerHTML`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

Comment: @Slavik - Give me code please

Comment: I like answer with `Element.cloneNode()`

Answer (score 1):

An approach to store `attributes` from one element to another can be achieved through [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

```
var newScript = document.currentScript.cloneNode();
// newScript has the same attributes as, document.currentScript
// now you can overwrite the src attribute,
newScript.src = "new_src";
```

With that, your `insert` function can be re-written as,

```
function insert(src, node) {
  var script = node.cloneNode();
  script.src = src;
  node.parentNode.insertBefore(script, node.nextSibling);
}
```

Which I had tested in my developers tools below,

```
# grabbed the first <script> tag on the page for brevity,
> insert("whatever",$$("script")[0])

# lets view the <script> tag we cloned from,
> $$("script")[0]
# returns, <script type=​"text/​javascript" async src=​"http:​/​/​engine.adzerk.net/​ados?t=1459514526146&request=...,"IsAsync":​true}​">​</script>​

# check the attributes on the cloned element,
> $$("script")[0].nextSibling
# returns, <script type=​"text/​javascript" async src=​"whatever">​</script>​
```